# How do I search page titles of open tabs in Firefox natively?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, productivity

I want to be able to search page titles of all my open tabs in Firefox without installing yet another resource-consuming add-on to do so. Is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Yes, this is possible natively in Firefox.**

In the address bar, simply prepend your search term with a *%* sign followed by a <kbd>space</kbd>:

```
% intel
```

[image]

Productivity geeks like myself can speed up this whole process by focusing the caret on the address bar with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, and then typing `% <searchterm>`.

Comment: The separation by `space` characters is mentioned in [this article](http://mzl.la/1zazb0J) on Firefox Help for "Awesome Bar". The order of keywords and special characters does not seem to matter.